# How to safely remove orphaned values in the Windows registry?

Tags: c, registry

I had an application installed on my windows machine which I removed, but it has left an orphaned drive icon under "My Computer".  Having dug through the registry, to find it by name, it seems to be associated with a GUID that occurs in other parts of the registry.  I'd like to write a quick C program to do the job, once I understand what it is I need to remove.  I understand the API, but what is all that cr*p in the registry?  Short question: what registry values do I need to remove to reliably delete the unused drive icon?  Longer question:  where do I find out how the windows registry is organised at that level, to achieve the required result?  I've looked on MSDN, but either the information I require is not there, or I don't know what I'm looking for (I'm not a windows programmer, but I do know a little about coding...).  RTFM answers welcome, I'd just like to know which FM to R...

Comment: Someone could make a pile o' cash writing that FM. Unfortunately, they'd have to invest at least twice that in the research....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tools like [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Short anser to the longer question:
No such documentation exists. The registry is a rather ad-hoc pile of data, shared between many developers in- and outside Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**RevoUninstaller**](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) if [**CCleaner**](http://www.ccleaner.com/) does not help and you have not already coded something for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

[TFM - About the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724182(VS.85).aspx)
[TFM - COM Registry Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694355(VS.85).aspx)
[TFM - Shell Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144110(VS.85).aspx)
[TFM - Registering Verbs for File Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165967.aspx)
[TFM - Registering Preview Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144144(VS.85).aspx)
[TFM - Registering Programs with Client Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144109(VS.85).aspx)

[As easy as eating pancakes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=registering&ac=8)